# Numpy: Inverse Transforming Different Size Array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get the hang of normalizing my data, doing some work on it and then changing it back.  When doing an inverse_transform do I have to always pass in the exact same shape as it was when I did a fit_transform?  The code below will give me a "non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,3)"

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

first = np.array([[  1.2345, 1.220000,1.26245],
 [  1.234,1.220000,7.0901],
 [  1.23450,1.22000,1.14795]])

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(first)
new_dataset = dataset[:,:1]
trainPredict2 = scaler.inverse_transform(new_dataset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to pass a data set with exactly the same shape, but the number of columns must match the original data set as each row is interpreted as a record and each column is interpreted as a feature. And you can not miss features for your testing data set, technically. So for instance, slicing the rows will still work:

```
new_dataset = dataset[:1,:]
trainPredict2 = scaler.inverse_transform(new_dataset)
```

This gives back the first row of your original data set:

```
trainPredict2
# array([[ 1.2345 ,  1.22   ,  1.26245]])
```

---

If you really want to inverse one or two features, you can calculate this by inversing the min-max transformation `x′:=(x−xmin)/(xmax−xmin)` formula, :

```
scaler.data_range_[:1] * dataset[:,:1] + scaler.data_min_[:1]
# array([[ 1.2345],
#        [ 1.234 ],
#        [ 1.2345]])
```

This gives back the first column of your original data set.

Comment: So if my data only consists of 1 column, I cannot inverse it again?  new_dataset was just an example of how my data may look after I work with it.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, after making predictions on my dataset I get an array that is in just 1 column (the predictions) , where when I did the fit_transform it was on multiple columns.  Now I want to transform the predictions back to the regular format using a inverse_transform but im getting different shapes.

Comment: Why do you need to do inverse transform on your predictions? The scaling is just for features. Do you mean you applied the scale transformation to your labels beforehand? If so, you probably need a reshape